# send email with attachment with php mailer

Tags: email, attachment, phpmailer

Can anybody tell me steps to send email with attachment with phpMailer.
I have prepared all codes to send email itself, and it is working fine but I did not understand how to send attachment. I have form and if I get value from a file input on POST it gives me only file name not full path. I think in order to addAttachment I need to get full path of file, right?
I don`t have to store file on server, just need to send it with email.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution:
Firstly, in my form I must include enctype="multipart/form-data" to send files, so it must be like this:

```
<form method="POST"  action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          inputs...
</form>
```

After that I get file this way:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['myfile'];
            }
```

Then I prepare path to this file which is now in temp directory and identify new filename:

```
$attachment_path = $this->file['tmp_name'];

 //If need to give new name for the file:
  //$newfilename = pathinfo(basename($this->file['name']));
  //$attachment_name = "attachment_new_name.".$newfilename['extension'];

$attachment_name = basename($this->file['name']);

$mail->AddAttachment($attachment_path, $attachment_name);
```

Done! file is attached now.

Comment: I only changed

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);

But it worked, thanks